# Word count with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I want to count words from below file types..
['pdf','xls','xlsx','odt','ppt','pptx','txt','doc','docx','rtf']/
currently my code reads text files only..
 please help me for other file types..

Below is my code..

```
<script>
 $('#file').change( function(event) {
    var imgpath=document.getElementById('file');
    if (!imgpath.value==""){
    var ext = imgpath.value.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(); 
        if($.inArray(ext, ['pdf','xls','xlsx','odt','ppt','pptx','txt','doc','docx','rtf']) != -1) {
        var f = event.target.files[0];
        if (f) {
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = function(e) { 
                var strings = "";
                var contents = e.target.result; alert(contents);
                var words = contents.match(/\S+/g).length; 
                $('#display_file_count').text(words);
            }
            r.readAsText(f);
        }
        }else{
            alert('file type not supported.');
            $('#file').val('');
        }
    }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: You are trying to could the file types that are infact elements of array, you can simply use .length

Comment: Some of those files cannot be accessed in the same manner as a text file as they are not plain text (pdf, xls, xlsx, odt, ppt, pptx, doc and docx for example). What you are attempting to do is not a trivial task, and not one suited to JS, assuming its even possible at all.

Comment: You need a reader for each type, to parse the file and outputs the words!

Comment: the "x" file formats you list are XML, which JS can easily search: `.documentElement.textContent.match(/\b\w+\b/g)`.